# Maven not using filePermissions and directoryPermissions on deploy

Tags: maven, maven-3

I am setting up Maven on a common, shared NFS directory under UNIX. In the site settings.xml, we have filePermissions and directoryPermissions setup like this:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>release.repo</id>
        <filePermissions>666</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>777</directoryPermissions>
        <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>snapshot.repo</id>
        <filePermissions>666</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>777</directoryPermissions>
        <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
```

We are also using profiles, so in the profile section, we have something like this:

```
<profile>
        <id>linux64</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>snapshot.repo</id>
                <name>Snapshot Repository</name>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <url>file:///path/maven_repo_snapshots</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>release.repo</id>
                <name>Release Repository</name>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <url>file:///path/maven_repo</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
```

In my user settings.xml I have something like this:

```
<settings>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>linux64</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

The repository ID matches the server ID. However, when we actually run a deploy, the filePermissions and directoryPermissions aren't being used.

Everything looks OK when we run help:effective-pom, help:effective-settings, and help:active-profiles. Is there something obvious I am missing?

The output of mvn -v =

```
$mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 02:44:56-0600)
Maven home: /path/apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_38, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_38/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.18-308.24.1.el5", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

We plan to look into a repository like Nexus at some point, but we wanted to simply the transition by not adding another piece of infrastructure to understand at this point.

Comment: Why not using a repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus or Archiva makes life easier. Furthermore parallel deployments on the same location via Maven on a file system are not supported as far as i know.

Comment: Edited post to address your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For various reasons, we decided to setup a Nexus server since we could never get the file permissions to work as documented.